# SQLLDR control file: Loading multiple files

Tags: sql, oracle, toad

Iam trying to load several data files into a single table. Now the files themselves have the following format:

```
                          file_uniqueidentifier.dat_date
```

My control file looks like this

```
    LOAD DATA
     INFILE '/home/user/file*.dat_*'
       into TABLE NEWFILES
         FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
          TRAILING NULLCOLS
                (
                     FIRSTNAME  CHAR NULLIF (FIRSTNAME=BLANKS)
                    ,LASTNAME   CHAR NULLIF (LASTNAME=BLANKS)
                             )
```

My SQLLDR on the other hand looks like this

```
                sqlldr control=loader.ctl, userid=user/pass@oracle, errors=99999,direct=true
```

The error produced is SQL*Loader-500 unable to open file (/home/user/file*.dat_*)  SQL*Loader-553 file not found

Does anyone have an idea as to how I can deal with this issue?

Comment: possible duplicate of [load multiple csv into one table by SQLLDR](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17405071/load-multiple-csv-into-one-table-by-sqlldr)

Answer (score 2):

`SQLLDR` does not recognize the wildcard. The only way to have it use multiple files to to list them explicitly. You could probably do this using a shell script.

Comment: The files can not be listed explicitly, they are in thousands.

Comment: This is why I suggested using a shell script.

Comment: Use a shell script like this:
`filename="$(ls /home/user/file*.dat_*)";
for curr_filename in ${filename[@]}
do
sqlldr userid/password@oracle control=loader.ctl data=$curr_filename;
done;`

Answer (score 1):

Your file naming convention seem like you can combine those files in to one making that one being used by the sqlldr control file. I don't know how you can combine those files into one file in Unix, but in Windows I can issue this command

```
copy file*.dat* file.dat
```

This command will read all the contents of the files that have the names that start with *file* and extension of *dat* and put in the *file.dat* file.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this option and this works fine for multiple files uploading into single table.

---

### -- SQL-Loader Basic Control File

```
options  ( skip=1 )
load data
  infile 'F:\oracle\dbHome\BIN\sqlloader\multi_file_insert\dept1.csv'           
  infile 'F:\oracle\dbHome\BIN\sqlloader\multi_file_insert\dept2.csv'           
  truncate into table   scott.dept2
fields terminated by ","       
optionally enclosed by '"' 
  ( DEPTNO
  , DNAME
  , LOC
  , entdate
  )
```