# load multiple csv into one table by SQLLDR

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-loader

I am using SQL LOADER to load multiple csv file in one table.
The process I found is very easy like

```
LOAD
  DATA 
  INFILE '/path/file1.csv'
  INFILE '/path/file2.csv'
  INFILE '/path/file3.csv'
  INFILE '/path/file4.csv'
  APPEND INTO TABLE TBL_DATA_FILE
    EVALUATE CHECK_CONSTRAINTS
    REENABLE DISABLED_CONSTRAINTS
    EXCEPTIONS EXCEPTION_TABLE
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY "," 
  OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
  TRAILING NULLCOLS
  ( 
    COL0,
    COL1,
    COL2,
    COL3,
    COL4
  )
```

But I don't want to use INFILE multiple time cause if I have more than 1000 files then I have to mention 1000 times INFILE in control file script.

So my question is: is there any other way (like any loop / any *.csv) to load multiple files without using multiple infile?

Thanks,
Bithun

Comment: How big are the files, do you have space to store them 2x? Are the files reachable from the database server?

Comment: yes... files are reachable... i execute my code and it is loaded successfully.....but i want to know whether there are any other way to load data.....withount using INFILE multiple times...

Comment: Can you write a script to generate this file?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Solution 1: Can you concatenate the 1000 files into on big file, which is then loaded by SQL*Loader. On unix, I'd use something like

```
cd path
cat file*.csv > all_files.csv
```

Answer (score 4):

Solution 2: Use external tables and load the data using a PL/SQL procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE myload AS
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1 .. 1000 LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE xtable LOCATION ('''||to_char(i,'FM9999')||'.csv'')';
    INSERT INTO mytable SELECT * FROM xtable;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use a wildcards (? for a single character, * for any number) like this:

```
infile 'file?.csv'
```

;)

Comment: I tried using wildcard "?", but it didn't work.
```SQL*Loader-500: Unable to open file (/tmp/csv/?_act.csv)
SQL*Loader-553: file not found
SQL*Loader-509: System error: No such file or directory
SQL*Loader-2026: the load was aborted because SQL Loader cannot continue.
```

Answer (score 1):

Loop over the files from the shell:

```
#!/bin/bash
for csvFile in `ls file*.csv`
do
    ln -s $csvFile tmpFile.csv
    sqlldr control=file_pointing_at_tmpFile.ctl
    rm tmpFile.csv
done
```

Answer (score -2):

```
OPTIONS (skip=1)
LOAD DATA
```

`INFILE /export/home/applmgr1/chalam/Upload/*.csv`

```
REPLACE INTO TABLE XX_TEST_FTP_UP
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(FULL_NAME,EMPLOYEE_NUMBER)
```

whether it will check all the `CSV` and load the data or not